# Add first + last elements, second + second to last elements etc. to a vector

Tags: c++

This is what I have so far. And it seems to only add the first+last, second+last etc. I can't figure out how to make it add the second+second-to-last and so on.
It is a dynamic vector, and iterators can't be used.

```
#include iostream
#include vector
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    vector<int> ack;
    int add;
    while(cin >> add)
    {
        ack.push_back(add);
    }

    for(size_t i = 0; i < ack.size(); i++)
    {
        cout << ack[i] + ack[ack.back() - 1] << endl;
    }
 }
```

Answer (score 2):

Your code is doubly wrong. `ack.back()` is just the value of the last element - that is unrelated to any operation you are trying to do. Also, `ack.back() - 1` is not a function of your loop index - so `ack[ack.back() - 1]` is just some constant that you will add every time in the loop.

Since you want the "last - Nth" element every time, that implies that you need to subtract something from the `size()`. So what you want to do is:

```
for(size_t i = 0; i < ack.size(); i++)
{
    cout << ack[i] + ack[ack.size() - i - 1] << endl;
}
```

Comment: Thanks! The output is printed twice though. So, if I enter 1,2,3,4 it outputs 5,5,5,5.

Comment: @ShaunMorgan Yep. What can we do to fix it?

Comment: I have no idea. I'm a beginner with programming. No catching on very easily.

Comment: @ShaunMorgan Just grab a piece of paper, and trace through the program by hand, iterating over `i` to see what every line prints and why.

Comment: I believe it is because it doesn't stop the loop. It goes to [0] + [3],  [1]+[2], [2]+[1], [3]+[0]. But I don't know how to fix this.

Comment: @shaun stop at the half way point. But then pls learn to debug the code by using a debugger. For sample code it's ok to put print statements. For complex code you need a debugger.

Comment: I solved this by changing the for to for(size_t i = 0; i < ack.size() - 1 - i; ++i)